# Model binder to decrypt string and convert to int

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model which has a property `id` of type `int`.

I pass the `id` in the url like `Detail/20` for fetching the data. But, now my customer says they don't want to see the `id`, since any one can modify and see other records.

Now, I've decided to encrypt and decrypt it, and assign it to another property: `encId`.

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    foreach(Employee e in empList)
    {
        e.encId = MyUtil.Encrypt(id,"sessionid");    
    }

    return View(empList);
}
```

Finally, I make my url like `Detail/WOgV16ZKsShQY4nF3REcNQ==/`.

Now, all I need is to decrypt it back to the original form and assign it to the property `id` of type `int`.

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id) //don't want (string id)
{

}
```

How can I write my model binder that decrypt and convert it to valid `id`? Also if any error/exception occurs, it has to redirect to 404 Error page. It might happen when user manually edits some useless text in the url (encrypted id).

Comment: 1) Why don't you use proper authorization to prevent users from accessing/modifying the records they should not be able to?
2) And, if you want to encrypt/decrypt, why don't you do the decryption in the controller action?

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not the way to go about securing your website and data.  Please take a look at the issues with [Security Through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).  You would be better off defining sets of permissions on each employee record and who can or cannot edit them.  Such an example could look like this:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
    if(MySecurityProvider.CanView(id, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name){
        return View();
    }
    Return RedirectToAction("PermissionIssue", "Errors");
}
```

With that said, to continue on the path you are on, simply do the decryption within the action result.

```
public ActionResult Detail(string Id)
{
    int actualId;
    try{
       actualId = MyUtil.Decrypt(id);
    }catch(Exception e){
         //someone mucked with my encryption string
         RedirectToAction("SomeError", "Errors");
    }
    var employee = MyEmployeeService.GetEmployeeById(actualId);
    if(employee == null){
         //This was a bad id
         RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Errors");
    }
    Return View(employee);
}
```